# How Parse XML Data to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, xml, dataframe

so I have this kind of xml data

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<CONSOLIDATED_LIST>
    <INDIVIDUALS>
        <INDIVIDUAL>
            <STUDENT_ID>1</STUDENT_ID>
            <FIRST_NAME>JAMES</FIRST_NAME>
            <SECOND_NAME>PETER</SECOND_NAME>
            <THIRD_NAME>SOMMER</THIRD_NAME>
            <DOB>
                <YEAR>2000</YEAR>
                <MONTH>JUNE</MONTH>
                <DATE>30</DATE>
            </DOB>
            <SCORE>
                <MATH>100</MATH>
                <PHYSICS>90</PHYSICS>
            </SCORE>
            <SCORE>
                <BIOLOGY>100</BIOLOGY>
            </SCORE>
            <SCORE>
                <Economic>100</Economic>
            </SCORE>
        </INDIVIDUAL>
        <INDIVIDUAL>
            <STUDENT_ID>2</STUDENT_ID>
            <FIRST_NAME>RICKY</FIRST_NAME>
            <SECOND_NAME>HUTTON</SECOND_NAME>
            <THIRD_NAME>LEE</THIRD_NAME>
            <DOB>
                <YEAR>2001</YEAR>
                <MONTH>MARCH</MONTH>
                <DATE>29</DATE>
            </DOB>
            <SCORE>
                <MATH>90</MATH>
                <PHYSICS>70</PHYSICS>
                <ENGLISH>70</ENGLISH>
            </SCORE>
            <SCORE>
                <Economic>100</Economic>
            </SCORE>
        </INDIVIDUAL>
    </INDIVIDUALS>
    <GROUPS>
        <GROUP>
            <GROUP_ID>1</GROUP_ID>
            <TEAM_LEADER>JAMES</TEAM_LEADER>
            <TEAM_MEMBER>PETER</TEAM_MEMBER>
        </GROUP>
    </GROUPS>

</CONSOLIDATED_LIST>
```

the goal is to parse this data in python pandas so I can use the data to do analysis.

I have tried several ways, but still have no clue what is missing. some is only works if the tree depth is only 2. some only works if there is only one branch after consolidated_list and I cant find the answer to parsing the part like DOB and SCORE in my example data

desired result is like this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

A possible option :

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = [] # collecting the data

for ind in ET.parse("file.xml").findall(".//INDIVIDUAL"):
    d = {}
    for c in ind:
        if not c:
            d[c.tag] = c.text
        else:
            d.setdefault(c.tag, []).append({e.tag: e.text for e in c})
    data.append(d)
```

---

```
# a custom func to format nested data
def joinested(lst, kv=False, sep=", "):
    # feel free to adjust the parameters
    return sep.join(f"{k}:{v}" if kv else v # << you may need to change ":"
                    for d in lst for k,v in d.items())
```

---

```py
# making the df
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["DOB"] = df["DOB"].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(
    joinested(x), format="%Y, %B, %d")).dt.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
df["SCORE"] = df["SCORE"].apply(joinested, kv=True) # add `sep` if needed
```

Output :

|  | STUDENT_ID | FIRST_NAME | SECOND_NAME | THIRD_NAME | DOB | SCORE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | JAMES | PETER | SOMMER | 2000/06/30 | MATH:100, PHYSICS:90, BIOLOGY:100, Economic:100 |
| 1 | 2 | RICKY | HUTTON | LEE | 2001/03/29 | MATH:90, PHYSICS:70, ENGLISH:70, Economic:100 |

<sup>[Old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/60549605-7cd8-45bc-8785-1ba975ed2234/view-source)</sup>

Comment: thanks a lot, what if there is another branch with same name e.g ```<score><biology>50</biology></score>```

Comment: Can you include that in your post by updating your `xml` example ?

Comment: the post has just been updated. some student ID has 2 score branch, some student ID has 3 or more.

Comment: it works thanks a lot